# Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error /cups/filter/hpps

Tags: printing, crash, cups-lpd

Ever since upgrading to 16.04, I have been getting repeated internal errors pointing to usr/lib/cups/filter/hpps. I am unsure how to correct the issue. The traceback indicates a crash with a "broken pipe error". The Lpstat indicates it involves the HP printers I use. I'm using the package 3.16.3+repack0-1. I've continuously reported these issues but they keep popping up occasionally. Is this a bug that is still being resolved or is this a driver that needs updating? Any clues?

Comment: Is it this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1446987

Comment: Well, I do have an HP printer, but I can print from it okay. It's a system error that will occasionally pop up but mostly comes when I boot up & log into an account. I submit an error report & then reboot & I get no more error boxes. It doesn't happen every time, either. Pretty random.

Answer (score 5):

I have observed the same. I am pretty sure it is this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1446987

The printer driver crashes if it runs into a network problem. To quote the issue description: "As Linux distributions have automatic crash handling/reporting systems this causes annoying pop-ups which irritate the users giving the impression of a more severe problem."

So nothing too bad - just annoying. It looks like hp is working on a fix (see end of issue comments). I'm thinking about uninstalling hplip for now.